# c# Insert Fixed Text to Cursor Position

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio, c#, cursor, text-cursor

I would Like to add to my Visual studio a shortcut or addin to add fixed text to the position where the cursor is on.
For example :
this is my current cs File:

```
public void foo(){
int x = 4 ;
**cursor Position**
}
```

when the shortcut or the addin triggered the code will be :

```
public void foo(){
int x = 4 ;
'my fixed text'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered snippets?

Comment: I dont know this tool.. can youe give me details or example?

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx

Comment: I look it and its good but I have mistake i need something else. I will try to explain again what I need :  (1) i  need to create hotkey for openning a form that I created.  (2) from this from I need to take text and need to write him into the cs file on the cursor position. the text from the form is not fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) for this.
Just save this is a .ahk file and it will work as intended:

```
c::
  SendInput, The text you need pasted
Return
```

Comment: I recommend AutoHotKey. However, The question is not about how to accomplish this goal, but how to accomplish it in C# language.